# Vim block identation issue

Tags: vim

I used CTRL+v, j...j, -> sequence to ident a block. It worked pretty well. Recently, it stopped working. The highlighted block does not move when I pressed -> (left key). Instead, additional column of the block got highlighted. Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: The current behaviour is the expected behaviour. The former behaviour was provided by some custom mapping or third-party plugin. Also, this is not the "left key" you are pressing.

Comment: Thanks. yes. I use plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: the correct key is > (angle bracket, not left key)

Comment: in visual mode, use  =  to indent